# Indexing lucene document with different analysers

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, full-text-search

Is it okay to index the lucene documents with two different analysers? Like i need to support both case-sensitive and case-insensitive search. So wondering if I can use two analysers for same document.

`writer.addDocument(doc,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30));
   writer.addDocument(doc,new custom_analyser);`

I am planning to have a custom analyser that supports all filter the standard analyser does except for lowercase filter.
While I try to search results from indices, I think we might end up getting duplicates..

Any comment/ideas?

EDIT:
@Simon

```
Analyzer defaultAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper wrapper = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(defaultAnalyzer);
wrapper.addAnalyzer("CaseSensitiveContents", new WhitespaceAnalyzer());

writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(index), wrapper, true, 
                         new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(100))

doc.add(new Field("contents", parser.getReader(), TermVector.YES));
doc.add(new Field("CaseSensitiveContents", parser.getReader(), TermVector.YES));
writer.add(doc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code would add two almost identical documents (except their casing) to your index.

How about adding two fields to one document, one being case sensitive, one not? You can use the `PerFieldAnalyzer` for this.

Comment: @Simon, I am getting a stream closed exception when I try to add same contents to two different feilds...how do I fix that?

Comment: It sounds like you're adding the same token stream twice? I've never seen this error when working with pure strings. I would need to see some code to debug this, preferably where you add your Fieldable (usually Field).

Comment: I would look into your calls to parser.getReader(). I do not know the inner workings of that method, but I would guess that it returns the same reader/stream twice. It is read from when inserting 'contents', and disposed of when it's time to read data for the 'CaseSensitiveContents'. Is it possible to index the strings directly instead? Like `new Field("...", parser.getText(), TermVector.YES)` or something?

Comment: Well..the parser method is a HTML parser, that parses the HTML files. It rips off the HTML tags and gives the reader stream. do you think it would be possible to read the stream into a different reader obj and pass that stream to the field?

Comment: Try first creating two instances of the html parser, one for each field. That should show if this is the problem, or something else is acting up.

Comment: @Simon - This work around for using case-sensitive/insensitive searches has slowed down the indexing and searching time, its noticeable. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: Potential problems may be that your html parser executes twice, or you have huge amounts of data. Have you tried a profiler?

Comment: No I haven't tried profiler, between I am converting all data from HTML parser to text and passing the text to field. I can't create instances of HTML parser that way. I think thats causing the delay. I think converting the reader to text is consuming a lot of time